# C++ implementation (XOR,IMPLIES,IFF)

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, xor

Truth table:

***P-----------Q-----------XOR-----------IMPLIES-----------IFF***

T-----------T--------------F---------------T-----------------T

T-----------F--------------T---------------F-----------------F

F-----------T--------------T---------------T-----------------F

F-----------F--------------F---------------T-----------------T

I want to know how to calculate XOR, IMPLIES,IFF using only and,or,not operators. Say for example XOR is - " ( p || Q ) && ! ( a && b ) ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, a general way to solve this.

So, you have a truth table, like this:

```
P   Q   f(P, Q)
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   1
```

Now, you can start by transcribing each row with a `1` like this:

```
//Row 2            3            4
      (!P && Q) || (P && !Q) || (P && Q)
```

Now you have the expression in disjunctive normal form and you need to simplify it. We learned a systematic simplification process in school, but i don't really remember it (maybe you can try to search on the internet for something like DNF expression simplification). You can also try to do it using logical axioms, such as [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), but that wouldn't be completely systematic.

Answer (score 1):

- XOR: `(p || q) && !(p && q)` or `p ^ q` or `p != q`
- IMPLIES: `(!p || q)`
- IFF: inverse of XOR?

Comment: actually what is the process ...... is it induction or there are some systematic way to solve this.